# Issue with coordinates on Google Maps v7

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm having an issue with the new version of the Google Maps application. I'm using an ACTION_VIEW to open the application in some certain coordinates:

```
            double latitude = mExperience.getExperienceLatitude();
            double longitude = mExperience.getExperienceLongitude();
            String label = mExperience.getdCode().getName();
            String uriBegin = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
            String query = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%f,%f(%s)", latitude, longitude, label);
            String encodedQuery = Uri.encode(query);
            String uriString = uriBegin + "?q=" + encodedQuery + "&z=16";
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
```

My final URI is correct, with something like:

```
geo:38.721714,-9.131110?q=38.721714%2C-9.131110(Place)&z=16
```

Now, when my phone is in Portuguese, the Google Maps app uses my Locale and somehow internally it searches for "38,721714,-9,131110" and it obviously doesn't find anything since it's a malformed search. When I use the phone in English it keeps the dots instead of commas and everything works fine.

Anyone else had the same issue? Is there a way to enforce the Locale upon sending an Intent?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for everyone having the same issue as I did, after updating the Google Maps application the problem was fixed. I guess I was with an older version of the new Google Maps application and it had this bug.